# Unexpected line in the seaborn bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, seaborn, visualization

```
stars = [9.7, 9.7, 9.5, 9.5, 9.4, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.2, 9.2]
episodes = ['The Last One',
 'The One Where Everybody Finds Out',
 'The Last One',
 'The One with the Embryos',
 'The One with the Prom Video',
 'The One with the Rumor',
 'The One with the Proposal',
 'The One with the Videotape',
 "The One with Monica and Chandler's Wedding: Part 2",
 "The One with Ross's Wedding"]

sns.barplot(stars, episodes, palette='inferno')
plt.xlabel('Stars') 
plt.ylabel('Episodes') 
plt.title('Top 10 Episodes according to Stars')
plt.xlim(9,10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Hello developers, Please help me!
Here Why I am getting an unexpected line in first bar?

Comment: You have two entries with the same name. Seaborn then shows their mean together with an errorbar. If you really want two last entries, you might add an extra space or so to one of them.

Comment: Gotcha thanks, I didn't notice this in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the line in the first bar is because there are two elements in the episodes list with value of the last one .

Comment: Thanks It worked after I change their value.